# In GraphQL, how to control DB query by client query?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I learn to use GraphQL these days. In my opinion, To build a query, I need to build three parts:

1. Schema

```
type User{
  id String
  name String
  cars [Car!]!
}
type Car{
  id String
}
type Query{
  user(id: String): User
}
```

2. DB Query function

```
{
  user: async function ({id}) {
    const user = await DB.user.findOne({id});
    const userCars = await DB.car.find({userId: id});
    user.cars = userCars;
    return cars;
  }
}
```

3. Client query

```
{
  user (id: "1") {
    name
    cars {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

That query returns a user's name and his cars. The DB query function **always** query for cars.

But sometimes I just need user's info:

```
{
  user (id: "1") {
    name
  }
}
```

I don't want to query for cars, so I hope to make my DB query function can auto choose to query for cars or not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL.js will support either object properties or methods for resolver functions; this is discussed in its page on [Object Types](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/).

One way to deal with this is just to insert an anonymous function directly into the returned object:

```javascript
{
  user: async function ({id}) {
    const user = await DB.user.findOne({id});
    user.cars = () => DB.car.find({userId: id});
    return cars;
  }
}
```

Another is to create a wrapper object with a class that provides the `id` property and (asynchronous, lazy) `cars` method; some examples of this are in the [GraphQL.js documentation](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/).  This approach tends to work in most GraphQL implementations in most languages.

Comment: A elegant solution. Save my time to write "if"!

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking into auto-creating/mapping from GraphQL query into db query.

Every queries are db/project specific, so you should create this mapping. You can easily do that with [graphql-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-fields) package.

There is copy pasted WHY section from the package:

> An underlying REST api may only return fields based on query params.
>
> ```
> {
>   user {
>     profile {
>       firstName
>     },
>     id
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> should request `/api/user?fields=profile,id`
>
> while
>
> ```
> {
>   user {
>     email
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> should request `/api/user?fields=email`
>   Implement your resolve method like so:
>
> ```
> resolve(root, args, context, info) {
>     const topLevelFields = Object.keys(graphqlFields(info));
>     return fetch(`/api/user?fields=${topLevelFields.join(',')}`);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's a more direct solution. I have looked into "info" but not found what I need. This module is useful!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid squeezing it all into one resolver function. Instead, create a separate ObjectType for `Cars` which has its own fields and its own resolver function. This way, the car query is only called if that field is requested.

In case you are using a RDS, join monster and data louder can help optimize performance of your queries.

- [Join Monster](https://github.com/acarl005/join-monster) which relies on generating one big join query and also solve the problem of only requesting exactly the fields you need from the DB
- [Cached and Batched SQL Data Source](https://github.com/cvburgess/SQLDataSource/) which uses facebook's dataloader under the hood - it wont solve the problem of which fields to query (although the example uses knex, which will make that a lot easier), but instead it can cache and batch your queries